# divide floating point numbers from two different outputs

Tags: bash, floating-point, division

I am writing a bash script that has 1) number of lines in a file matching a pattern and 2) total lines in a file.

a) To get the number of lines in a file within a directory that had a specific pattern I used grep -c "pattern" f*

b) For overall line count in each file within the directory I used
wc -l f*

I am trying to divide the output from 2 by 1. I have tried a for loop

```
for i in $a
do
printf "%f\n" $(($b/$a)
echo i
done
```

but that returns an error `syntax error in expression (error token is "first file in directory")`

I also have tried

```
bc "$b/$a"
```

which does not work either

I am not sure if this is possible to do -- any advice appreciated. thanks!

Sample: grep -c *f generates a list like this

```
myfile1 500
myfile2 0
myfile3 14
myfile4 18
```

and wc -l *f generates a list like this:

```
myfile1 500
myfile2 500
myfile3 500
myfile4 238
```

I want my output to be the outcome of output for grep/wc divided so for example

```
myfile1 1
myfile2 0
myfile3 0.28
myfile4 0.07
```

Answer (score 3):

`bash` only supports integer math so the following will print the (silently) truncated integer value:

```
$ a=3 b=5
$ printf "%f\n" $(($b/$a))
1.000000
```

`bc` is one solution and with a tweak of OP's current code:

```
$ bc <<< "scale=2;$b/$a"
1.66

# or

$ echo "scale=4;$b/$a" | bc
1.6666
```

---

If you happen to start with real/float numbers the `printf` approach will error (more specifically, the `$(($b/$a))` will generate an error):

```
$ a=3.55 b=8.456
$ printf "%f\n" $(($b/$a))
-bash: 8.456/3.55: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".456/3.55")
```

`bc` to the rescue:

```
$ bc <<< "scale=2;$b/$a"
2.38

# or

$ echo "scale=4;$b/$a" | bc
2.3819
```

---

**NOTE:** in OP's parent code there should be a test for `$a=0` and if true then decide how to proceed (eg, set answer to `0`; skip the calculation; print a warning message) otherwise the this code will generate a `divide by zero` error

Answer (score 2):

`bash` doesn't have builtin floating-point arithmetic, but it can be simulated to some extent. For instance, in order to truncate the value of the fraction `a/b` to two decimal places (without rounding):

```
q=$((100*a/b)) # hoping multiplication won't overflow
echo ${q:0:-2}.${q: -2}
```

The number of decimal places can be made parametric:

```
n=4
q=$((10**n*a/b))
echo ${q:0:-n}.${q: -n}
```

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` will do it all:

```
awk '/pattern/{a+=1}END{print a/NR}' f*
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> jot 93765431 | 
>
> mawk -v __='[13579]6$' 'BEGIN { 
>
> _^=__=_*=FS=__ }{ __+=_<NF } END { if (___=NR) {
>
>    printf(" %\47*.f / %\47-*.f ( %.*f %% )\n",
>           _+=++_*_*_++,__,_,___,_--,_*__/___*_) } }'
> ```

```
4,688,271 / 93,765,431  ( 4.99999941343 % )
```

- `filtering pattern` = `[13579]6$`